# my html5 canvas background and paddle wont show up in browser

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am having issues loading my javascript code in the browser here is the issue:
I am trying to load a white paddle with a white ball and a big black square (for the background)
when i try to load it up in chrome nothing appears i dont know why here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>paddle</title>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script>
 const paddle_width = 100
 const paddle_thickness = 10
 var paddleX = 400
 var canvas
    var canvasContext
  var ballX = 5
  var ballSpeedX = 5
  var ballY = 5
  var ballSpeedY = 5
function updateMousePos(evt) {
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
var root = document.documentElement;
var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft
//var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top = - root.scrollT
   paddleX = mouseX
}
  window.onload = function() {

  var fps = 30;
  setInterval(updateAll, 1000/fps)
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d")
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", updateMousePos)
}
 function updateAll() {
c
 ballY += ballSpeedY
 ballX += ballSpeedX
if(ballX > canvas.width) {
ballSpeedX *= -1
}
if(ballX < 0) {
ballSpeedX *= -1
}
if(ballY > canvas.height) {
ballSpeedY *= -1
}
 if(ballY < 0) {
  ballSpeedY *= -1
 }

canvasContext.fillStyle = "black"
canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

canvasContext.fillStyle = "white";
canvasContext.beginPath()
 canvasContext.arc(ballX, ballY, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
      canvasContext.fill()
     }


   </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Load your page and  hit F12 to bring up dev tools (if using a laptop, desktop, or the like). Click the console tab and you will see the error. First line of `updateAll` function